# Add CORS options to AWS websocket API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, socket.io, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed an AWS websocket API Gateway, backed by lambda functions.  I can successfully connect and exercise the websocket service from websocketking.com

When I try connecting from my client app (Angular, socket.io v3) I get the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sockets.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NRSfmDM' from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

How do I configure an AWS websocket API gateway to support CORS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought it can be done in same way as for HTTP API - via CLI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html

However it seems there is no option to allow CORS for WebSocket protocol. I am seeing the message `An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateApi operation: Cors is not supported for WEBSOCKET protocolType`

Based on that I assume there is no support for the CORS at the moment for WebSocket protocol.

If it is an option for you, you can use custom domain for the API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-custom-domain-names.html, so that both your web client and API will have same origin.

Comment: Thanks Milan - the link refers to the HTTP API, whereas I'm using the WebSocket API

Comment: Thanks @Journeyman, I did not noticed it's solely for HTTP API.

Comment: Setting custom domain is not possible. This is the message from aws.
`Currently, WebSocket APIs cannot be mixed with REST APIs or HTTP APIs on the same domain name.`
I wonder if you were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Milan, the AWS Websocket API Gateway protocol does not support CORS, and you would need to deploy your client-facing application to the same domain as your Websocket API.

I found that you will not need to specify CORS if you use WebSocket API on your client-side instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket
on your client-side.

Basically, WebSocket protocol by default is not forcing your browser to check CORS policies:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-secure-your-websocket-connections-d0be0996c556/

But since v3, socket.io explicitly requires you to enable them: https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/